# Sqoop Import Create File Name with Date

Tags: sqoop

I am working on a Sqoop script which I want to create the target directory with the current date. Do we have some options in Sqoop like --target-dir /dir1/$DATE. If so, what is the exact syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly add $DATE to sqoop but
You can use shell script and pass the parameters in the shell script For e.g.

```
    # -----------myscript.sh------------------

    DATE=`date`

 echo   
  sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>/<DB> --table TABLE_NAME  --username user -password pass -m 1  --target-dir /user/$DATE

    #------------end script----------------------
```

Now

add permission to script file

```
chmod 777 myscript.sh
```

Run the script file

```
./myscript.sh
```